# SQL Server Query Help Needed - Archive items not seen within last 2 years

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm currently in the middle of writing an SQL query for the following scenario.

A piece of equipment can get inspected over time and I would like to archive any items from the system that have not been inspected within the last 2 years.

At the minute I have this:

```
DECLARE @TwoYearsAgo DATETIME;
SET @TwoYearsAgo = DATEADD(year, -2, GETDATE());

SELECT I.Equipment_Label, I.Inspection_ID
FROM Inspections 
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT Time_Of_Inspection, Inspections.Equipment_Label, Inspections.Inspection_ID
    FROM Inspections 
    INNER JOIN Equipment ON Inspections.Equipment_Label = Equipment.Equipment_Label
    WHERE Time_Of_Inspection BETWEEN @TwoYearsAgo AND GETDATE() AND Equipment.Archived = 0
) I
```

I know that my outer apply will get all items that have been inspected within the last 2 years but I'm unsure what to put in the where clause after the outer apply to get any that haven't been inspected within the last two years that aren't in the outer apply results.

Comment: You're doing something weird with the `outer apply` and I'm surprised you're not seeing a huge result set with lots of duplicate rows. If you're looking for inspections that happened *before* two years ago then why didn't you use `where Time_Of_Inspection < @TwoYearsAgo`? And don't forget you've got that `Equipment.Archived = 0` condition in there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out with the below query.. Assuming `Time_Of_Inspection` is `dataetime` field

```
DECLARE @TwoYearsAgo DATETIME;
SET @TwoYearsAgo = DATEADD(year, -2, GETDATE());

SELECT A.Equipment_Label, A.Inspection_ID
FROM Inspections A
WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 1
            FROM Inspections B
            INNER JOIN Equipment E ON B.Equipment_Label = E.Equipment_Label
            WHERE Time_Of_Inspection BETWEEN @TwoYearsAgo AND GETDATE() AND E.Archived = 0
            AND A.Inspection_ID=B.Inspection_ID
        )
```

Comment: This returns no rows

Answer (score 0):

Inspections held more then  2 years ago and having no following inspections for last 2 years and Equipment.Archived = 0.

```
DECLARE @TwoYearsAgo DATETIME;
SET @TwoYearsAgo = DATEADD(year, -2, GETDATE());

SELECT I.Equipment_Label, I.Inspection_ID
FROM Inspections I
WHERE i.Time_Of_Inspection < @TwoYearsAgo
    AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Inspections i2
    INNER JOIN Equipment ON i2.Equipment_Label = Equipment.Equipment_Label 
      AND i2.Equipment_Label = I.Equipment_Label
      AND i2.Time_Of_Inspection BETWEEN @TwoYearsAgo AND GETDATE() 
      AND Equipment.Archived = 0
    )
```

Comment: This returns inspections that were done today and recently. I need the list that haven't been done since 2 years ago from today's date